# Get current user

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

```
class Makale(models.Model):
    baslik = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    yazi = models.TextField()
    tarih = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    kategori = models.ForeignKey('Blog.Kategori')
    yazar = models.ForeignKey('Blog.Yazar',blank=True, editable=False)

class Yazar(models.Model):
    kullanici = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tam_adi = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    katilma_tarihi = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    yazi = models.TextField()
```

I am creating user in admin panel I want name of that user.
how should I do ?? I don't know very well django :(

Comment: Where exactly do you want it?

Comment: {{ request.user.username }} in template and request.user.username in views.py.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused that what you exactly asking.i guess you need the username of logged in current username and to display it in your html

In `views.py` apply this

```
username = request.user.username
return render(request, 'index.html',{'username':username})
```

**or**

simply use this tag in your **html** and get the current logged in username

```
{{ request.user.username }}
```

Comment: This isn't right.. but you almost have it.  `request.user` IS an instance of `auth.User`, so `username = request.user.username` IS the username of the current user.  That's it.